# laradock環境で、docker-compose up時に、「E: Unable to locate package php7.1-xdebug」というエラーが出てしまう。

Tags: laravel, docker-compose

ほぼ初心者のエンジニアです。
3年前に、別のエンジニアが構築したサービスの再立ち上げをやっています。
そのサービスは、webサービスで、バックエンドはphp Laravel、フロントはnuxt.jsで書かれており、
AWS環境に別のエンジニアが、laradockを使って、環境を構築してくれました。
（現在そのエンジニアに連絡が取れておらず、なんとかやろうとしています）

新しい環境は、さくらVPSで、OSはCentOS8で、nginxでVirtual Host化してあり、ドメインを一つ登録した状態で別のサービスが動いていますが、それにもう一つドメインを追加して今回のサービスのための環境も構築しようとしています。
ドメインは登録し終わり、とにかくサーバ上に置いた、index.phpは見られることを確認した状態です。

そこに、

- php Laravelのプロジェクトのディレクトリ
- フロントのディレクトリ
- laradockのディレクトリ
  を設置しました。これはAWS上で前のエンジニアが環境構築してくれた時と同じ形です。
  ここで、前のエンジニアが残してくれていた環境構築のためのざっくり覚書に沿って、dockerを立ち上げようとしたところ、下記コマンドでエラーが出てしまいました。

```
$ docker-compose up -d nginx redis mailhog workspace mysql elasticsearch
```

エラー内容

```
Step 61/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_XDEBUG} = true ]; then     apt-get install -y php${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}-xdebug &&     sed -i 's/^;//g' /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini &&     echo "alias phpunit='php -dzend_extension=xdebug.so /var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit'" >> ~/.bashrc ;fi
 ---> Running in 528bc8f69a5b
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-xdebug
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-xdebug'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-xdebug'
ERROR: Service 'workspace' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c if [ ${INSTALL_XDEBUG} = true ]; then     apt-get install -y php${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}-xdebug &&     sed -i 's/^;//g' /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini &&     echo "alias phpunit='php -dzend_extension=xdebug.so /var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit'" >> ~/.bashrc ;fi' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

nginx redis mailhogまでは立ち上がるようですが、workspaceのところでコマンドエラーが出てしまいます。
`E: Unable to locate package php7.1-xdebug` というのは、適切なバージョンのphp-xdebugのパッケージが取れません、といったエラーかと思うので、xdebugを別途入れようとしてみましたが、全く同じパッケージは見つかりません。
一方で、今最新のxdebugは入れることができました。（同様の英語のstackoverflowを見て、php-pecl-xdebug3というパッケージをyum installしました）
入れた後で、再度docker-compose upを試しましたが、変わりません。
phpinfo()で確認してみると、xdebugは入っています。

これは、別のパッケージを入れたりする必要があるのでしょうか。
それとも、workspaceのdocker-compose.ymlの方をいじったりする必要がありますでしょうか。

そもそも、過去に用意してもらっていたlaradockを使う必要はなく、別のdockerを用意したり、今置いているディレクトリ内にphpの同じバージョンなどをインストールしてlaravelの環境構築するべきかもしれないと思っています。

また、そもそもVPS内にnginxでドメイン振り分けをおこなっているのに、laradock内にさらにnginxのコンテナを立ち上げる必要があるかなども気になっています（別の質問も入れ込んでおりすみません）

見当違いのこともとにかく色々あるかと思うのですが、何かしらのとっかかりをいただけると大変助かります。

何卒どうぞよろしくお願いします！

=====

9.14 追記します docker-compose.yml
おそらくlaradockというものに、そもそもついているymlで、この中から使うサービスだけ立ち上げるという形なのではないかと思います。ymlがものすごく大きくて貼り付けられないので、最初の `workspace` の部分のみ貼り付けます。

```
version: '3'

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}
  backend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}

volumes:
  mysql:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  percona:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  mssql:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  postgres:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  memcached:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  redis:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  neo4j:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  mariadb:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  mongo:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  minio:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  rethinkdb:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  phpmyadmin:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  adminer:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  aerospike:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  caddy:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  elasticsearch:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}

services:

### Workspace Utilities ##################################
    workspace:
      build:
        context: ./workspace
        args:
          - LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}
          - LARADOCK_PHALCON_VERSION=${PHALCON_VERSION}
          - INSTALL_SUBVERSION=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SUBVERSION}
          - INSTALL_XDEBUG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XDEBUG}
          - INSTALL_PHPDBG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHPDBG}
          - INSTALL_BLACKFIRE=${INSTALL_BLACKFIRE}
          - INSTALL_SSH2=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SSH2}
          - INSTALL_GMP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_GMP}
          - INSTALL_SOAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SOAP}
          - INSTALL_LDAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LDAP}
          - INSTALL_IMAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAP}
          - INSTALL_MONGO=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MONGO}
          - INSTALL_AMQP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AMQP}
          - INSTALL_PHPREDIS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHPREDIS}
          - INSTALL_MSSQL=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MSSQL}
          - INSTALL_NODE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NODE}
          - NPM_REGISTRY=${WORKSPACE_NPM_REGISTRY}
          - INSTALL_YARN=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_YARN}
          - INSTALL_NPM_GULP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_GULP}
          - INSTALL_NPM_BOWER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_BOWER}
          - INSTALL_NPM_VUE_CLI=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_VUE_CLI}
          - INSTALL_DRUSH=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DRUSH}
          - INSTALL_DRUPAL_CONSOLE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DRUPAL_CONSOLE}
          - INSTALL_AEROSPIKE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AEROSPIKE}
          - AEROSPIKE_PHP_REPOSITORY=${AEROSPIKE_PHP_REPOSITORY}
          - INSTALL_V8JS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_V8JS}
          - COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL}
          - COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST}
          - INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH}
          - INSTALL_LARAVEL_ENVOY=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LARAVEL_ENVOY}
          - INSTALL_LARAVEL_INSTALLER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LARAVEL_INSTALLER}
          - INSTALL_DEPLOYER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DEPLOYER}
          - INSTALL_PRESTISSIMO=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PRESTISSIMO}
          - INSTALL_LINUXBREW=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LINUXBREW}
          - INSTALL_MC=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MC}
          - INSTALL_SYMFONY=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SYMFONY}
          - INSTALL_PYTHON=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PYTHON}
          - INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS}
          - INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK}
          - INSTALL_TERRAFORM=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_TERRAFORM}
          - INSTALL_DUSK_DEPS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DUSK_DEPS}
          - INSTALL_PG_CLIENT=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PG_CLIENT}
          - INSTALL_PHALCON=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHALCON}
          - INSTALL_SWOOLE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SWOOLE}
          - INSTALL_LIBPNG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LIBPNG}
          - INSTALL_IONCUBE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IONCUBE}
          - INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT}
          - PUID=${WORKSPACE_PUID}
          - PGID=${WORKSPACE_PGID}
          - CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION}
          - NODE_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_NODE_VERSION}
          - YARN_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_YARN_VERSION}
          - DRUSH_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_DRUSH_VERSION}
          - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
          - BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID=${BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID}
          - BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN=${BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN}
      volumes:
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
      ports:
        - "${WORKSPACE_SSH_PORT}:22"
      tty: true
      environment:
        - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=${PHP_IDE_CONFIG}
        - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker-in-docker:2375
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend
      links:
        - docker-in-docker

### PHP-FPM ##############################################
    php-fpm:
      build:
        context: ./php-fpm
        args:
          - LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}
          - LARADOCK_PHALCON_VERSION=${PHALCON_VERSION}
          - INSTALL_XDEBUG=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XDEBUG}
          - INSTALL_PHPDBG=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPDBG}
          - INSTALL_BLACKFIRE=${INSTALL_BLACKFIRE}
          - INSTALL_SSH2=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SSH2}
          - INSTALL_SOAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SOAP}
          - INSTALL_IMAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAP}
          - INSTALL_MONGO=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MONGO}
          - INSTALL_AMQP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_AMQP}
          - INSTALL_MSSQL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MSSQL}
          - INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE}
          - INSTALL_BCMATH=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_BCMATH}
          - INSTALL_GMP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GMP}
          - INSTALL_PHPREDIS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPREDIS}
          - INSTALL_MEMCACHED=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MEMCACHED}
          - INSTALL_OPCACHE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_OPCACHE}
          - INSTALL_EXIF=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_EXIF}
          - INSTALL_AEROSPIKE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_AEROSPIKE}
          - AEROSPIKE_PHP_REPOSITORY=${AEROSPIKE_PHP_REPOSITORY}
          - INSTALL_MYSQLI=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MYSQLI}
          - INSTALL_PGSQL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PGSQL}
          - INSTALL_PG_CLIENT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PG_CLIENT}
          - INSTALL_INTL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_INTL}
          - INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT}
          - INSTALL_LDAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_LDAP}
          - INSTALL_PHALCON=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHALCON}
          - INSTALL_SWOOLE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SWOOLE}
          - INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS}
          - INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK}
          - INSTALL_CALENDAR=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_CALENDAR}
          - INSTALL_FAKETIME=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_FAKETIME}
          - INSTALL_IONCUBE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IONCUBE}
          - INSTALL_YAML=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_YAML}
      volumes:
        - ./php-fpm/php${PHP_VERSION}.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
      expose:
        - "9000"
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
      environment:
        - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=${PHP_IDE_CONFIG}
        - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker-in-docker:2375
        - FAKETIME=${PHP_FPM_FAKETIME}
      depends_on:
        - workspace
      networks:
        - backend
      links:
        - docker-in-docker
```

2022.09.16追記
同様のスレッドを教えていただき、 `apt-get udate &&` を最初に追加するということを試してみましたが、同様のエラーが出てしまいました。
https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1847

```
Step 61/183 : RUN if [ ${INSTALL_XDEBUG} = true ]; then     apt-get update && apt-get install -y php${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}-xdebug &&     sed -i 's/^;//g' /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini &&     echo "alias phpunit='php -dzend_extension=xdebug.so /var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit'" >> ~/.bashrc ;fi
 ---> Running in ca2f4197e26c
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [99.8 kB]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [99.8 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [97.4 kB]
Fetched 297 kB in 2s (139 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-xdebug
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-xdebug'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-xdebug'
ERROR: Service 'workspace' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c if [ ${INSTALL_XDEBUG} = true ]; then     apt-get update && apt-get install -y php${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}-xdebug &&     sed -i 's/^;//g' /etc/php/${LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION}/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini &&     echo "alias phpunit='php -dzend_extension=xdebug.so /var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit'" >> ~/.bashrc ;fi' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Comment: Dockerfile の内容等も追記してみてください。 / エラーに出ているのは apt-get (Debian/Ubuntu) なのに、"yum でインストールした" (CentOS) など環境の整合性が取れていないように見えます。

Comment: 質問文を読むに、 「`yum install`しました」はコンテナの外でしょうか。であれば、環境は分かれているので当然ながらこの文脈では意味のないことをしていそうです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございますm(_ _)m
VPS自体はCentOSが入ってしまっており、以前AWSで環境構築してもらっていた時はおっしゃる通りUbuntuでした。
apt-getということは、やはりUbuntuですよね。。。
そもそものOSの整合性の問題の可能性はあると思っていました。（dockerやOSの理解度が高くないため、明確にそのせいであるとの判断もできずにおりました。）

Comment: hint: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1847

Comment: @hinaloe hintありがとうございます！　やってみます！

Comment: いただいたリンクに従い、workspaceのDockerfileに `apt-get update &&` を追加してbuildしてみましたが、同じエラーが出てしまいました。

Comment: エラーログを見ると、環境がXenial(Ubuntu16.04 LTS)、すでにEoLとなっているものを使用しているように見えます。一方で、当該ppaには18.04以降のみにxdebugが存在するようです。現在のlaradock/workspaceは20.04ベースのように見えます。古いベースイメージを使い続けている可能性があるなら、 `--pull` を付加してビルドをしてみるといいでしょう。ただし、laradockはあくまでも開発環境として構築されているものです(汎用性を高くしようとした結果複雑肥大になっているとも昔から言われていますが)が、質問文を読むと本番環境に使用しようとしているようにも見えます。であれば、再考が必要かもしれません。

Comment: @hinaloe 再度コメントありがとうございます。一度Dockerfile内のコマンドを、xdebug関連のパッケージを探して、出てきたものを入れるという記述に変更してみて、立ち上がるかどうかをやってみようと思います。
その上で、長期的にはご指摘の通りlaradockではなく別で本番環境を作るよう、再考しようと思います。重ねてコメントいただき感謝いたします！